# Unable to Navigate to teams channel from Teams app in MS Teams desktop application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, deep-linking, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

i have created MSTeam app by using MSTeam App Studio and added one SharePoint page has a personal tab.

[image]

in the app we are showing all the respective Teams with link to open it, but On click on the "click to view" it supposed to navigate to specific Team general channel but failed to open it.

Navigate URL format we have used - [https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/{channelID}/{channelname}?groupId={Team](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/%7BchannelID%7D/%7Bchannelname%7D?groupId=%7BTeam) ID}&tenantId={tenent id}

But onclick on hyperlink its still stayed in same Team application shows the below screen
[image]

Nothing is happening on click on launch it now, am i doing any wrong please let me know.

Excepted behavior on click on link the user need to be navigated to specific team channel

Answer (score 0):

here is the way described by [teams documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-deep-links-to-channel-conversation). kindly follow the way and also trying logging out and again logging into application. also you are missing few things in the url

Comment: @Krishnareddy- Kindly follow the format provided in the documentation and check it once.